# Constant temperature operation of microheater

Tags: operational-amplifier, temperature, comparator, wheatstone-bridge, heater

I have been trying to make a constant temperature control for microheaters based on this wheatstone bridge circuit, using a trim pot to set the temperature setpoint. The purpose is to keep the heater at the same temperature if there is wind flow on it.  The problem is with the current schematic, sometimes it works. If I blow wind over the microheater to cool it,  the BJT draws more current and the heater stays at the same resistance (ala temperature). But some other times the op-amp output hits saturation and it doesn't keep the microheater constant anymore. How can I avoid this saturation problem and make it more robust? Any help is appreciated. Thank you ! [image]

Answer (score 0):

If the op-amp is saturating positive then there is insufficient power to balance the bridge. You could increase the voltage or reduce the voltage drop in the emitter follower. Or decrease the resistance of the heater so it draws more current.

If the op-amp is saturating at 0V out, then you've run into the bistable nature of this circuit*. You need to force it to a positive solution. One way might be to parallel the transistor with a resistor to overcome the maximum offset voltage of the op-amp under all possible start-up conditions. This will limit the minimum power available to the heater.

* Think about the solution without the transistor emitter follower and with an ideal op-amp- it could settle equally well at +Vx or -Vx. With a small op-amp offset voltage (which could be of either polarity) it may be happier to settle at 0V, or a small bit of transient at startup could kick it the wrong way.

Comment: The op-amp is saturating positive, for example if the supply voltage is 8V then it saturates to somewhere close to 6.64 V. I am assuming this is because LM324 is not rail to rail.

I can't really change the resistance of the heater. The idea is that the heater resistance will remain constant, whether there is wind cooling or no cooling effect. When the circuit works properly the heater draws around 10-15 mA more than it would when there is no cooling.


What would be a good solution to avoid saturation on either end>

Comment: You could get a bit more voltage by changing to a R-R op-amp. You could get a lot more by increasing the supply voltage. Since power is proportional to V^2 a little goes a long way. The other issue is independent and I indicated a possible solution.